# If for each valuation there is an $n$ such that $[[\phi_n]]=1$, then there is an $m$ such that $\vdash \phi_1 \lor \cdots \lor \phi_m$

Tags: logic

Consider an infinite set $\{\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3, \cdots\}$. If for each valuation there is an $n$ such that $[[\phi_n]]=1$, then there is an $m$ such that $\vdash \phi_1 \lor \cdots \lor \phi_m$.

it's an exercise from the [Van Dalen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540208798)'s book. I tried to solve problem with contradiction, first, we assume that for every $m$ we have that  $\not\vdash \phi_1 \lor \cdots \lor \phi_m$ it means that for each $m$ we have that $\not \vdash \phi_m$ because if we have that $\vdash \phi_m$ then we can use Introducing of $\lor$ rule and then we had $\vdash \phi_1 \lor \cdots \phi_m$
and it's not possible. now we use soundness and completeness theorem and for all $m$ we have $\not \vDash \phi_m$. so for arbitrary valuation there is no $n$ such that $[[\phi_n]] = 1$. I think my prove is not right. book hinted to use Compactness Theorem that I didn't use it.

Comment: This claim requires the assumption that the universe isn't empty.

Comment: @DanielV: I don't see it. Choose $k$ so that $\phi_k$ holds in the empty model (by assumption) and assume every nonempty model satisfies $\phi_1 \lor \cdots \lor  \phi_m$. Then every model (empty or not) satisfies $\phi_1 \lor \cdots \lor \phi_{k + m}$. Although, because the OP talks about "valuation", I wonder if they are asking about propositional logic.

Comment: @CarlMummert: i don't think it matters whether the question is about propositional logic or sentences in predicate logic.n Please see my answer and comment if I have missed something.

Comment: I was going based on the title, missed the part in the body where it said "infinite set".

Comment: @Rob Arthan: the answer works the same either way, but the issue of an empty domain isn't relevant in the propositional case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi_m = \phi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \phi_m$. If for every $m$, $\not\vdash \psi_m$, any finite subset of the set $\Psi= \{\lnot\psi_1, \lnot\psi_2, \ldots\}$ is consistent. Hence, by compactness, $\Psi$ has a model, say $\mathbf{M}$. In $\mathbf{M}$, no $\phi_n$ holds (contradicting the assumption that for every valuation, there is an $n$ such that $[[\phi_n]]$ is true).